# Get-AppxPackage in vbscript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I need to use vbscript to list all of the application packages on a computer. I know you can do it in PowerShell using Get-AppxPackage. Is there a way to do this in vbscript?

Comment: You could call Powershell from VBscript using WScript Shell but that sounds horrible.

Comment: Why do you have to use VBscript ?

Comment: Well, you could use WSShell Exec to run Powershell and execute the cmdlet and capture the result. A better solution would be to just use powershell instead of VBScript.